# Why is disable_with not working for a rails form_for?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@foobar) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

          ~~~form stuff~~~

  <%= submit_tag "submit",  data => { disable_with: "Processing" }, :class => "btn btn-info btn-block" %>
<% end %>
```

I'm running rails 3.2.11. I have the jquery-rails gem installed and all my other jQuery stuff works. Why am I still able to hit the "submit" button multiple times while it's still loading? How do I disable the button?

Answer (score 6):

Check the following in your raw html:

- the submit button has data-disable-with attribute
- your page includes jQuery js. For me I have:

  - https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
- you page includes jquery_ujs js. For me I have:

  - /javascripts/jquery_ujs.js

You can read more on https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs.

Answer (score 3):

```
<%= button_tag 'submit', data: { disable_with: "Processing..." }, class: 'btn btn-info btn-block' %>
```